# In Spring AOP AfterReturning Advice Annotation, how to get back a return value from the advice next to the point cut method

Tags: java, spring, annotations, aop, pointcut

I have a small need, am using AfterReturning annotation.
Here is an example code:

//File: applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"   
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd   
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop   
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd"> 

    <bean id="opBean" class="com.javatpoint.Operation">   </bean>  
    <bean id="trackMyBean" class="com.javatpoint.TrackOperation"></bean>  

    <bean class="org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator"></bean>  

</beans>
```

//File: Operation.java

```
package com.javatpoint;  

    public  class Operation{  

    public int p1(){System.out.println("p1() method invoked");return 2;}  
    public int p2(){System.out.println("p2() method invoked");return 3;}  
    public int m1(){System.out.println("m1() method invoked"); int x=p1();//Here I want to get the return from the advice (z), so the method m1 can process and return to main}  
    public int m2(){System.out.println("m2() method invoked"); int y=p2();//Here I want to get the return from the advice (z), so the method m2 can process and return to main}  
            }
```

//File: TrackOperation.java

```
package com.javatpoint;  

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;  
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;  
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;  

@Aspect  
public class TrackOperation{  

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* Operation.p*(..))", returning= result")  
    public int myadvice(JoinPoint jp,Object result)//it is advice (after returning advice)  
{  
        System.out.println("additional concern");  
        System.out.println("Method Signature: "  + jp.getSignature());  
        System.out.println("Result in advice: "+result);  
        System.out.println("end of after returning advice, but trying to return a value to business method..."); 
       int z = (int) result;
        z = z*3;
        return z;         
    }  
}
```

//File: Test.java

```
package com.javatpoint;  
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;  
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Test{  
    public static void main(String[] args){  
        ApplicationContext context = new 
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        Operation e = (Operation) context.getBean("opBean");
        System.out.println("calling m..."); 
        System.out.println(e.m());
        System.out.println("calling k...");
        System.out.println(e.k());  
    }  
}
```

End of the program and want a quick reply. Here am sending capturing the result from the business method but i want to return from advice itself so that i can print it in the main business class `m1` & `m2`.

Inside the main business class `p1` & `p2` are the pointcut defined

Comment: Spring uses proxies to apply AOP. Internal method calls won't get intercepted. Hence it won't work.

Comment: Are you using Spring to run this?

Comment: Yes, Spring 4.0

Comment: @M.Deinum ProceedingJoinPoint is there for Around advice to return back to business method. but am looking for it in after return.         `public interface ProceedingJoinPoint extends JoinPoint {  public Object proceed(Object[] args);   }                                                                                                                    public Object twiceAsOld(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint, int i) { 
return thisJoinPoint.proceed(new Object[]{i*2});  }`                       //something like this happens in Around, but looking for afterreturning

Comment: I'm nowhere talking about proceedingjoinponts so no idea where you get that from. I only speak about proxies.. Spring applies AOP through proxies regardless of the type of advice (before, after, after returning OR around) it is a proxy. A limitation of proxies is that self invocations aren't intercepted (again regardless of the type of advice). It won't work due to the self invocations. Even if it would work it wouldn't in your case due to the fact that with an `@AfterReturning` you cannot change the return value (only an around advice can do that).

Comment: So, is there any way to fulfill my objective in around advice. Then what will be the returning in `(pointcut = "execution(* Operation.p*(..))", returning= result")`